# Thinning a Renewal Process - Poisson Generalization

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

If we have a Poisson point process with rate $\lambda$ and we keep each of its point with probability $p$, we obtain another Poisson point process with rate $\lambda p$. Does this result holds for a general Renewal point process? i.e.,

> If in a renewal point process with rate $\lambda$, we keep each point with probability $p$ independently, do we obtain another renewal point process?

Comment: If each point is independently kept with probability $p$, then yes.  Each new renewal time is independent of the previous ones.  This seems  similar to other questions you asked, what is the context here?